# Ricci curvature and shape operator in hypersurfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Show that the Ricci curvature of a hypersurface $M\subset\mathbb{R}_v^{n+1}$ is given by:

> $$Ric(V,W)=\epsilon[\langle SV,W\rangle]trace S-\langle SV,W\rangle$$

$S$ is the shape operator, defined as $Sv=-\nabla_V U$ where U is a unit normal vector.

$\langle Sv,u\rangle=\langle \Pi(v,w),u\rangle$

i tried to use the Gauss equation of curvature on the ricci curvature definition, but that does not yield $S$, at least I do not see how. This question does not seem like a straightforward calculation.

**Question:**

Can anyone provide me with some hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\pi(v,w)$?

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: @ArcticChar It is the sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your formula has a mistake in its last term.

In general, we have the relation $$R(X,Y)Z = \langle SY, Z\rangle SX - \langle SX,Z\rangle SY$$between the curvature tensor $R$ of a hypersurface and the shape operator $S$ associated with a chosen unit normal field. See p. 16 on Section 1.4 of Dajczer & Tojeiro's *Submanifold Theory*.

We want to trace the above equation in the variable $X$ only. The left side gives ${\rm Ric}(Y,Z)$ by definition. In the right side, tracing $\langle SY,Z\rangle SX$ in $X$ obviously yields $\langle SY,Z\rangle \,{\rm tr}(S)$. As for the very last term, we have that ${\rm tr}(X\mapsto \langle SX,Z\rangle SY) = \langle S^2Y,Z\rangle = \langle SY,SZ\rangle$. Hence $${\rm Ric}(Y,Z) = \langle SY,Z\rangle\,{\rm tr}(S) - \langle SY,SZ\rangle.$$

---

Here, we're using the following linear algebra fact: whenever $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, $v\in V$ and $f\in V^*$, and we define $T\colon V\to V$ by $T(x) = f(x)v$, then ${\rm tr}(T) = f(v)$. If $f=0$ this is trivial, and if $f\neq 0$ compute the trace using a basis $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ of $V$ with $f(e_1) = 1$ and $f(e_j) = 0$ for $j\geq 2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the bibliographic reference. I suppose you are using $R(X,Y)Z =\tilde{R}(X,Y)Z + \langle SY, Z\rangle SX - \langle SX,Z\rangle SY$. How did you get rid of $\tilde{R}$?

Comment: Yes, that's the formula. Your hypersurface is inside Euclidean space, so $\bar{R}=0$.